# Google Apps Script - Always allow app to run

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

I wrote a script in GSheets we use at my work that uses custom menus.  Because everyone is set to "Can view" on the template, they are forced to make a copy as to not affect the template.

The downside of that is each spreadsheet will require authorization to run every single time the form is sent in and the menus need to be used which makes the process more cumbersome.  Is there a way I can provide authorization to run the code, whether it be through an onOpen trigger or some other means?

The code includes moving sheets into folders, extracting data to a central spreadsheet, and sending emails.  The email does not need to come from the user, it can be sent as a no-reply/anonymous user if that helps.